# read a lot of file and xml to json in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, xml, file, converters

I am completely noobie in node.js and I am a university researcher.
I have a lot of files in XML and JSON format, I have a lot of folders and files, I need read it and create one standard (in JSON/CSV) and finally loading it in MySQL database, any tips? do you know npm packages for it or completely solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many packages for converting xml to json like `xmljs`, `xml2json`, etc..

But looks like you need transforming to standard format for inserting into database as well.

I have this problem myself and i wrote [camaro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/camaro) for this purpose: convert and transform xml to json

All i have to do is to write an output template that i would like my xml to be converted too using xpath syntax like below

Of course you can just flatten all the attribute you need ; the below is just example of what camaro can do.

```
const transform = require('camaro')
const fs = require('fs')

const xml = fs.readFileSync('examples/ean.xml', 'utf-8')
const template = {
    cache_key: '/HotelListResponse/cacheKey',
    hotels: ['//HotelSummary', {
        hotel_id: 'hotelId',
        name: 'name',
        rooms: ['RoomRateDetailsList/RoomRateDetails', {
            rates: ['RateInfos/RateInfo', {
                currency: 'ChargeableRateInfo/@currencyCode',
                non_refundable: 'boolean(nonRefundable = "true")',
                price: 'number(ChargeableRateInfo/@total)'
            }],
            room_name: 'roomDescription',
            room_type_id: 'roomTypeCode'
        }]
    }],
    session_id: '/HotelListResponse/customerSessionId'
}

const result = transform(xml, template)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tuananh
Is it possible to use attr of a tag as key or value? Some of my data value i have in attr like `<name type="sub-name">Hotel name</name>` or `<hotelName id='12345'>Hotel name </name>` it is possible to do in camaro?

And I have doesn't pure data like `<name type="sub-name">Hotel <nameHotel>Hilton</nameHotel></name>` It is possible to remove tag `nameHotel` and save it as `{name: 'Hotel Hilton'}`
Thank you very much

Comment: right now, it's not possible to use xpath in key yet but i'll consider it in the future.